# Flutter Lottie: Works on Lottie player but not in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, lottie, bodymovin

Lottie animation works absolutely fine in lottie player but does not work in Flutter Web or Flutter Android. (Haven't tested on iOS)

**Animation:**

https://lottiefiles.com/113275-sad-character

**Code:**

```
LottieBuilder.network("https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_7gs6bvae.json",
                      controller: lottieController,)
```

This is how it looks on Android or Flutter Web:

[image]

Comment: Same issue is observed on iOS simulator too :) and its flickering too

Comment: Same thing observe on flutter web, I also download the file and render it with Lottie.asset, but it's the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the lottie help section about an issue, and they said some of the animation features are not supported.

You can check here
https://prnt.sc/tSKXVZDgjBE5

https://lottiefiles.com/supported-features

Comment: Any way to use Lottie Web on Flutter?

Comment: You can try other animations if some aren't working, I've tried this and it works.  https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_AQEOul.json       Lottie file:https://lottiefiles.com/9582-liquid-4-dot-loader

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar plugin that supports Flutter; you can give https://pag.art/  a try.

Comment: Answer is unclear
As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).